# regex for javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
<input type="text" name="address" pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z ,\.\/\-&']{0,}">
```

It will allow all except of few special characters but i don't want '//' '///' or any special character repetition like this. what should i change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-write the pattern as

```
pattern="(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]*(?:[ ,./&'-][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)?"
```

See JS demo:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="address" pattern="(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]*(?:[ ,./&'-][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)?">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note that `^` and `$` are added by default, but in case you are using some additional frameworks that override the *pattern* attribute, you need to add the anchors to the pattern explicitly:

```
^(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]*(?:[ ,./&'-][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)?$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]*(?:[ ,./&'-][0-9a-zA-Z]*)*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters/digits
  - `(?:[ ,./&'-][0-9a-zA-Z]*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of:

    - `[ ,./&'-]` - a space, `,`, `.`, `/` (no need to escape it!), `&`, `'` or `-` (no need to escape it at the end of the character class, but you can)
    - `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` - **one or more** ASCII letters/digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a negative lookahead to check repetition :
`(?!.*([ ,./&'-])\1)[0-9a-zA-Z ,./&'-]*`
This will reject strings with a space, `,`, `.`, `/`, `&`, `'`, or `-` repeated.